# How to use Strings as Printables in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a function that takes a parameter of type Printable:

```
func logMessage(message: Printable) {
    // ...
}
```

Strangely, this doesn't work as expected when passing in Strings.

This doesn't compile:

```
logMessage("some string \(someVariable)")

// Neither does this:
let aString = "aString"
logMessage(aString)
```

This however compiles:

```
logMessage("A string")
// This works too:
let aString: Printable = "a string"
logMessage(aString)
```

This is quite confusing. It seems that in some cases String implements Printable and in others not.

In addition, it seems that string interpolation always produces a String that does not implement Printable. This crashes at runtime with a cast error:

```
let aString = "a string"
let interpolatedString = "contains \(aString)"
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `String` doesn't conform to `Printable`.  The reason this compiles:

```
let aString: Printable = "Ceci n'est pas une String"
```

is that you aren't creating a `String` with that literal – you're creating an `NSString` (which *is* `Printable`).

Generally, in Swift, it’s usually better to write generic functions *constrained* by protocols.  So instead of

```
func logMessage(message: Printable) {
    // ...
}
```

you would probably be better off writing:

```
func logMessage<T: Printable>(message: T) {
    // ...
}
```

This approach has a number of advantages – better type-safety and avoiding type erasure, more performant etc.  You can read more about this stuff [here](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/03/26/protocols-and-generics-2/).

But you'll still hit a problem because you can't pass in a `String`.  You have two options here.  First, just don't constraint it at all:

```
func logMessage<T>(message: T) {
    // ...then use toString(message) to create a String if you need one,
    // or use string interpolation or print()
}
```

This will work with `String`, and in fact will also work with anything that isn’t `Printable` as well (though you'll get quite a unhelpful output involving the mangled classname).

Or, you could use `Streamable` which strings *do* conform to:

```
func logMessage<T: Streamable>(message: T) {
    println(message)
}

let s: String = "hello"
logMessage(s)
```

I think I read a while back on twitter one of the Swift team mention that the reason `String` doesn't conform to `Printable` is exactly because they didn't want people using `Printable` directly like this and that it’s better to always use `toString` or similar.

Comment: I filed a radar on this a while ago that was closed as *Behaves correctly* with this note: "There is no reason to use Printable as a type or a generic constraint.  println() and toString() work with any type, and one should use that instead of accessing the ‘description’ property."

Comment: @NateCook yeah personally I think it's reasonable to be able to specify that the type needs to provide a properly formatted description instead of a mangled type name as part of a function signature

Comment: Kind of unexpected that String doesn't implement Printable. I guess the third solution then would be to implement Printable in an extension on String.

Comment: @MihaiDamian I agree that it's unexpected, but essentially what Apple is saying is to write `<T>` functions, not `<T: Printable>`, and use `toString()` wherever you might have used the `description` property.

Comment: So I'm curious then: if I'm not even using a protocol for the parameter why is logMessage<T>(message: T) better than logMessage(message: Any). Is it just to help the compiler with optimizations since the type will be determined at compile time?